# Failed to delete Azure Batch Pool (Stays in Allocation State "Stopping")

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have created a Azure Batch Pool inside a Batch Account. After playing with the scaling formular for a while the pool now says, it is in allocation state "stopping".

This allocation state is the shown state since about two weeks now.
Neither resizing using the resize formular (blocked by a "stopping" overlay in the portal) nor deleting the pool works.

After I requested a delete, the pool now has the state "deleting", but stays at allocation state "stopping". 
Currently the pool has one node running (which it shouldn't according to the formular). This node can still be used for tasks.

[Current Pool Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Ozy.jpg)

So how can I delete the pool?

Answer (score 0):

A pool's `Allocation State` refers to resize operations ongoing on the pool. When it is in `stopping` state that means that the previous resize operation (perhaps due to your autoscale formula) is in the process of being stopped.

If the `Allocation State` has been like that for two weeks, something may be wrong with your formula (or the pool/nodes may not be usable).

A pool's `State` refers to the general state of the pool, e.g., `active`, `deleting`, or `upgrading`. When you issue a delete pool request, the state will move from its prior state to `deleting` independent of the `Allocation State` (although if the `Allocation State` was `resizing`, may move to `stopping`).

Your pool should eventually delete by itself after issuing the delete pool request. If it does not in a reasonable time frame, e.g., within 1 hour or so (typical deletion should happen within 5-15min), you can request an Azure support ticket detailing the issue.